# Google Charts JSON structure - what is incorrect

Tags: javascript, json, google-visualization

Appreciate any help on this one.

I am serving up JSON from my server but the data is not being displayed on my table. There are no javascript errors, suggesting an issue with my JSON(using sample data in the JS function works...).

Here is the JSON;

```
    {
        "cols": [
            {"label": "month","type": "string"},
            {"label": "date","type": "date"},
            {"label": "amount","type": "number"},
            {"label": "extype","type": "string"},
            {"label": "claimed","type": "boolean"}
        ],
        "rows": [
            {"c":["2016-10","2016-10-01",{"v":38.09,"f":"$38.09"},"Dinner",true]},
            {"c":["2016-10","2016-10-02",{"v":30.07,"f":"$30.07"},"Lunch",true]},
            {"c":["2016-10","2016-10-03",{"v":44.7,"f":"$44.7"},"Dinner",true]}
        ]
    }
```

Here is my javascript function used to render the table. The JSON above is passed to the function as `dataset`

```
    function drawTable(dataset,options){
        'use strict';
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(dataset);
        var cssClassNames = {
            'tableRow': '',
            'hoverTableRow': '',
            'headerCell': 'd',
            'tableCell': ''};
        options.cssClassNames = cssClassNames;
        var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('tableChart'));
        table.draw(data, options);
    }
```

Here is the output as rendered (note only the amount shows);

[image: Table Issue]

Comment: I see no `month` in your code - you've left some important information out of your question

Comment: My bad, I have added it, the columns do not show values now. I will add an edit

Comment: `The error I get is` any clue which line of code causes this error?

Comment: Apologies, the error was on my server side. I will close the question and open a new one for the next issue. (I think that's the way I'm supposed to. Thanks for your comments)

Comment: @JaromandaX Sorry, it didn't let me post another. I've edited the above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**first**, each column should be defined using object notation, similar to the amount column

```
{"c":[{"v":"2016-10"},{"v":"Date(2016, 9, 1)"},{"v":38.09,"f":"$38.09"},{"v":"Dinner"},{"v":true}]}
```

**next,** for the second column to be an actual date, the format will need to change...

from --> `"2016-10-01"`

to --> `"Date(2016, 9, 1)"`

note: months are zero based using this approach (9 = October)

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var jsonData = {
      "cols": [
        {"label": "month","type": "string"},
        {"label": "date","type": "date"},
        {"label": "amount","type": "number"},
        {"label": "extype","type": "string"},
        {"label": "claimed","type": "boolean"}
      ],
      "rows": [
        {"c":[{"v":"2016-10"},{"v":"Date(2016, 9, 1)"},{"v":38.09,"f":"$38.09"},{"v":"Dinner"},{"v":true}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"2016-10"},{"v":"Date(2016, 9, 2)"},{"v":30.07,"f":"$30.07"},{"v":"Lunch"},{"v":true}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"2016-10"},{"v":"Date(2016, 9, 3)"},{"v":44.7,"f":"$44.7"},{"v":"Dinner"},{"v":true}]}
      ]
    };

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('tableChart'));
    table.draw(data);
  },
  packages:['table']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="tableChart"></div>
```

Comment: I got it, I added the object notiation with v,f but good to know that I can remove the f when it's not being used. Thanks for your help, I will implement the changes tonight after work and let you know how I get on.